# load Output parameters from SQL stored procedure c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to load output parameters from my SQL stored procedure.

```
USE [EdiMon_Beta]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetClients] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@sender nvarchar(max),
@subSender nvarchar(max),
@receiver nvarchar(max),
@subReceiver nvarchar(max),
@msgTypeID int,

@ErrorMsg nvarchar(max) = null OUTPUT,
@processId int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
@senderId int,
@subSenderId int,
@receiverId int,
@subReceiverId int



SELECT
    @senderId = ID
FROM [dbo].[Party_Client]
WHERE
    [Number] LIKE @sender
IF(@senderId IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorMsg = 'Sender does not exist'
    RETURN ;
END


SELECT
    @subSenderId = ID
FROM [dbo].[Party_Client]
WHERE
    [Number] LIKE @subSender
    AND ParentId = @senderId
    AND IsSubClient = 1
IF(@subSenderId IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorMsg = 'SubSender does not exist'
    RETURN ;
END


SELECT
    @receiver = ID
FROM [dbo].[Party_Client]
WHERE
    [Number] LIKE @receiver
IF(@receiverId IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorMsg = 'Receiver does not exist'
    RETURN;
END


SELECT
    @subReceiverId = ID
FROM [dbo].[Party_Client]
WHERE
    [Number] LIKE @subReceiver
    AND ParentId = @receiverId
    AND IsSubClient = 1
IF(@subReceiverId IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorMsg = 'SubReceiver does not exist'
    RETURN ;
END


SELECT @processId = ID FROM [dbo].[Party_Processes]
WHERE MsgTypeId = @msgTypeID
AND SenderId = @senderId
AND ReceiverId = @receiverId

END
```

And reading it with c# code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetClients", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sender", sender));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@subSender", subSender));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@receiver", receiver));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@subReceiver", subReceiver));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@msgTypeID", msgTypeID));

        var errorMsgParam = command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrorMsg", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1));
        errorMsgParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        var processIdParam = command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@processId", SqlDbType.Int, -1));
        processIdParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var processIDResult = command.Parameters["@processId"].Value;
        var errorMsgResult = command.Parameters["@ErrorMsg"].Value;

        processID = (int)processIDResult;
        errorMsg = errorMsgResult.ToString();
    }
}
```

The thing is, I always get null as result. This is Helper class for xsl mapping in biztalk. All the input parameters are directly from the map. I want to check our database, if these clients exist and also, if process which using them exist.

thanks for your help :)

Comment: In the past, I added stored procedure also to my EDMX and called entities.storedprocedure(arg1, arg2); where arg2 is an ObjectParameter

Comment: It is not clear what is null. Is the ErrorMsg,  the processId or both parameters are null?

Comment: Both of them. I did a small test inside the c# class and it shows i got null for both of them.

Comment: Did you have an empty try/catch? Just try without catch should not compile

Comment: No i just didnt copy it here. There are some useless lines of code and after them catch(Exception ex){ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();}

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `.AddWithValue()` instead of `.Add()` for input parameters? There's a chance that SqlParameter constructor interprets second parameter as type.

Comment: The .add() works fine for input parameters. I have different method in the same project wich call much easier Stored Procedure and there it works. I dont think the problem is in input parameters. I think I am doing somethink wrong with reading the output params, but I cant tell what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i solved this. Problem was in 2 or 3 places. For first i had mistake in my SQL stored procedure which is not universal so i didnt post it here (it applies only to my project). The other mistake was in converting my output from stored procedure:

```
processID = command.Parameters["@processId"].Value as int?;
errorMsg = command.Parameters["@ErrorMsg"].Value == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : command.Parameters["@ErrorMsg"].Value.ToString();
```

where processID is declared as "int?" and errorMsg is declared as "string".

Thanks for all the help.